# Try something 5 times with Rx

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive

I'd like to try something every second for five seconds, return false if they are all false, and return true the first time one is true. Imperatively, it'd look like this:

```
bool TryFiveTimes()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (Fn())
            return true;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'd like to do this using Rx, but can't think of a neat way. My current attempt is:

```
bool TryFiveTimes()
{
    return Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Take(5)
        .Select(_ => Fn())
        .Scan(false, (curr, prev) => curr || prev)
        .Last();
}
```

This will give the correct result, but won't return early if `Fn()` returns true before the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `Concat` with `Return` like this:

```
bool TryFiveTimes()
{
    return Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Take(5)
        .Select(_ => Fn())
        .Where(x => x)
        .Concat(Observable.Return(false))
        .First();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For your implementation just use `.First()` method instead of `.Last()`

```
    static bool TryFiveTimes()
    {
        return Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .Take(5)
            .Select(_ => Fn())
            .Scan(false, (curr, prev) => curr || prev)
            .FirstOrDefault(v => v);
    }

    static int counters = 0;
    static bool Fn()
    {
        counters++;
        Console.WriteLine(counters);
        return counters > 2;
    }
```

[EDIT]: Added code which will prove that `Fn` method will be executed only before it first time returns `True`

Also, you do not really need `Scan()` here, shorter version is:

```
    return Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Take(5)
        .Select(_ => Fn())
        .FirstOrDefault(v => v);
```

Comment: I don't think this works if all 5 return false. In that case I'd like it to return false and instead it throws.

Comment: Than use FirstOrDefault() instead of First(). I have updated code.